# Alter Webform "To Email Address" based on some values using PHP in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I want to change email addresses based on postal codes entered by users.
My code looks something like below:

```
    function my_webform_tracker_webform_submission_render_alter(&$renderable) { 
    $node_id = (int)$renderable['#node']->nid;
    if ($node_id == 257) {
        $postal_code = (int)$renderable['#submission']->data[5][0];
        if($postal_code >= 14000 && $postal_code <= 14990) {
            $renderable['#email'][email] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";
            $renderable['#node']->webform['emails'][1]['email'] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";
            $renderable['#node']->webform['emails'][2]['email'] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";
            //print "<pre>"; print_r($renderable); exit;
        }
    }   
}
```

I tried a lot but the email id seems to be not changed.

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: This line look suspicious : $renderable['#email'][email] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com"; email got no quotes.
Maybe you wanted to write :
$renderable['#email']['email'] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";

Comment: the hook_webform_submission_render_alter() will alter how is displayed the results of the submissions made with your webform in back office.
So it will not change the value, at best you will hide them with another value when viewing this screen.
If it is what you are trying to do, best is to begin by activating the devel module and just make a dpm($renderable);
So you will have a better idea of what are the values in your renderable variable (and even got the path to the values so you can copy paste it in your code to change them).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to dinamycally change the email after the user enter a postal code on the screen?
If so you need to make an ajax call on the field postal code (detect a change) to reload the field email of your webform.

Also I will go with a hook_form_alter on the webform (hook_form_"webform id"_alter()) rather than the hook you are using

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, actually I was using wrong hook to do the task. The right one should be "hook_webform_submission_presave". So my code will look like,

```
    function my_webform_tracker_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
      $postal_code = (int)$renderable['#submission']->data[5][0];
      if($postal_code >= 14000 && $postal_code <= 14990) {
        $node->webform['emails'][1]['email'] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";
        $node->webform['emails'][2]['email'] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";      
      }
    }
```

Thank You everyone for help!!